# successfully building but the wsdl file not found?

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

i try to generate wsdl file using jaxws maven plugin
finaly:"successfully building" but my wsdl file is not generate, it is normaly in the folder \target\surefire-reports 
but i don't have it after the building

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BSCSwebservices Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:0.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
 [WARNING] The POM for org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices\target\surefire-reports
```

---

```
T E S T S
```

---

```
Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [BSCSwebservices] in [C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices\target\BSCSwebservices]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1042 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices\target\BSCSwebservices.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:1.11:wsgen (default) @ BSCSwebservices ---

warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:30.437s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 02 23:00:03 WAT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/40M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this  a part of pom.xml

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                <configuration>
                <sei>com.ws.BillingAccountRead</sei>
                <genwsdl>true</genwsdl>  
                 <keep>true</keep>

        </configuration>
                <phase>package</phase>      
                        <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>


                </execution>

        </executions>


    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

when i use mvn clean package -X

```
<configuration>
 <destDir default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
 <extension default-value="false"/>
 <genWsdl default-value="false"/>
 <keep default-value="false">true</keep>
 <pluginArtifactMap>${plugin.artifactMap}</pluginArtifactMap>
 <pluginArtifacts>${plugin.artifacts}</pluginArtifacts>
 <project>${project}</project>
 <resourceDestDir default-value="${project.build.directory}/jaxws/wsgen/wsdl"/>

 <sei>com.ws.BillingAccountRead</sei>
 <verbose default-value="false">true</verbose>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe it's generated to somewhere else? Did you search for it? Maybe it's just generated temporarily and later something deletes it?

Comment: no it is not generated, is this problem has a relation with lifecycle or not and where is possible can i find it .thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would want to build the wsdl in the 'generate-sources' phase or maybe 'generate-resources' instead of 'package'

Comment: it is the same no wsdl file but in markers of eclipse this message appeared when i used generate-sources;Description Resource Path Location Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:1.11:wsgen  pom.xml  line 177 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to generate the wsdl in `${resourceDestDir}`
Configure it like below with **verbose = true**, and execute the mvn command with **-X** flag, then look the maven log carefully.

```
<executions>
                <execution>
                <configuration>
                <sei>com.ws.BillingAccountRead</sei>
                <genwsdl>true</genwsdl>  
                 <keep>true</keep>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
                <phase>package</phase>      
                        <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>


                </execution>

        </executions>
```

Comment: Good idea for debug. -X will give a lots of output, but you can figure out better what's going on.

Comment: Can you share the output of -X flag ?

Comment: the only warning when i used mvn clean package - X:[INFO] Building BSCSwebservices Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:0.4 is invalid
 transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging f
r more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dpendencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more detail

Answer (score -1):

Try to build using -X or -e to get more info from the log

Comment: build not available lifecycle